# Integral Conversion To Spherical Coordinates

Tags: definite-integrals, spherical-coordinates

"Integrate $G(x,y,z) = x^2$ over the unit sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1.$"

Alright, so using the formula

$\int \int_R x^2 \sqrt{ 1+ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}} dA$

and working it down, I arrive at the integral:

$\int \int_R \frac{x^2}{z} dA$

When I try to convert this to polar coordinates, it becomes very messy, and when I look at the given solution they convert it to *spherical* coordinates. This is very odd to me, as I was under the impression that spherical coordinates were only used in a triple integral. The "official" conversion results in:

$\int_o^{2\pi} \int_o^{\pi} sin^3 (\phi) cos^2(\theta)d\phi d\theta$

And I have no idea how they arrived at that. If anyone could point me in the right direction here, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The exact wording is "integrate the given function over the given surface," and the section is titled Surface Integrals, so pretty sure that it is indeed the sphere surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually spherical coordinates are for volumes.  But if you are on the surface of the sphere, you set $\rho = 1$

$x = \cos\theta \sin \phi\\
y = \sin\theta \sin \phi\\
z = \cos \phi$

$ dy\;dx= \| (\frac {dx}{d\phi},\frac {dy}{d\phi}, \frac {dz}{d\phi}) \times (\frac {dx}{d\theta},\frac {dy}{d\theta}, \frac {dz}{d\theta})\|d\phi\;d\theta$

$dy\;dx = \sin\phi \;d\phi\;d\theta$

$\iint (\cos\theta \sin \phi)^2 \sin\phi \;d\phi\;d\theta$

Comment: Ohhhhhh, I see, thank you! Both good answers, but yours is more straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Parametrize with spherical coordinates

Note $\rho \sin (\phi)=r$ and $\rho \cos (\phi)=z$. This gives that,

$$\vec r(\phi,\theta)=\langle 1\sin (\phi) \cos (\theta), 1\sin (\phi) \sin (\phi), 1 \cos (\phi) \rangle$$

Now we need to compute $|r_\phi \times r_\theta|$. Lucky for me already know if there was a $\rho$ instead of $1$ above I would get $\rho^2 \sin (\phi)$ because that is the Jacobian associated with a change to spherical coordinates. So we get $1^2 \sin (\phi)$. Hence $dS=1^2 \sin (\phi) dA$.

So then

$$\iint_{S} x^2 dS=\iint (\sin (\phi) \cos (\theta))^2 1^2 \sin (\phi) dA$$

Of course $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ and $\phi \in [0,\pi]$.